# devexpress c# update sql database

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress

I have problem to update my database.. when I calculate the unit price and Lprofit just I saw the values in my GridView but in my SQL database nothing.. so how can update it automatically?

```
private void Chillers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'chillersDataSet1.OrnekTbl' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.ornekTblTableAdapter1.Fill(this.chillersDataSet1.OrnekTbl);

    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'chillersDataSet.OrnekTbl' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.ornekTblTableAdapter.Fill(this.chillersDataSet.OrnekTbl);

    try
    {
        this.Validate();

        this.ornekTblTableAdapter.Update(this.chillersDataSet.OrnekTbl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }

    InitMDBData();

    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        var totalprice = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotalPrice"));
        var quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Quantity"));
        gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "UnitPrice", (totalprice / quantity));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        var totPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotPrice"));
        var totalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotalPrice"));
        gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "Lprofit", (totPrice - totalPrice));
        this.ornekTblTableAdapter1.Update(this.chillersDataSet1.OrnekTbl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging or running the software compiled?
The default setting in Visual Studio is that when you are debugging it will make a copy of the database and each change you do will not be saved to the actual database.

Select the databases in Solution Explorer and change the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". This way it will make changes to your database in debugg.

EDIT: Looking in your source code I can also see that you are missing an update call. When you want to write to the database do something like this:

```
ornekTblTableAdapter.EndEdit();
ornekTblTableAdapter.Update();
```

(see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx)